# Show if the set $\{x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^3:\vert x\vert +\vert y \vert=2\}$ is a smooth surface

Tags: differential-geometry

My assumption is that this won't be a smooth surface because of the absolute values. Because if I look at the function $f(x,y)=\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert-2$ it has "edges". But not sure how to actually show something is not a surface.

Comment: What’s your definition of surface?

Comment: A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a surface if for ever point $p\in S$ there is an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and an open set $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing p such that $S\cap W$ is homeomorphic to $U$.

Comment: $U\in\mathbb{R}^2$ sorry.

Comment: In fact, it doesn’t matter whether it has ‘edge’ or ‘vertex’. For example, you can find homeomorphi between open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and small part of that rectangular cylinder near edge.

Comment: So it is a surface?

Comment: Yes it is!${}{}{}$

Comment: So how would I find the surface patches for this surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need to check at a point on edge. Let $P = (2, 0, 0) \in S$. Consider the open neighborhood
$$
W = S\cap \{(x, y, z)\,:\, x>0, y^{2} + z^{2}<1\}
$$
then we can check that this is homeomorphic to the open unit disk $D$ by $\phi:W\to D$ defined as 
$$
\phi(x, y, z) = (y, z).
$$

To show that it's smooth, you may think that the surface is not smooth since it is so *edgy*. However, that's not true. For example, you may observe that the above map $\phi$ is just projection to a plane. Now consider two small open neighborhood of a given point of $S$ on an edge, and let $\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}$ be appropriate projections to a plane, which gives a chart. Now you can see that the transition map is an *identity map* on their intersection, which is definitely smooth!

We can start with easier example. Let $C = \{(x, y)\,:\, y = |x|\}$ be a graph of $f(x) = |x|$, which seems to be a non-smooth curve (and it is, in some sense). 
However, we can give this curve a smooth structure by the following way - just project it to the $x$-axis. It is each to check that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ by the projection, and we can just transport smooth structure on the real line ($x$-axis) to $C$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put smooth surface in the original question.

Comment: @AColoredReptile That's okay since actually, that surface is also smooth! I edited.